# Use NSFetchedResultsController to get data in 3 tables

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-data

I'm using CoreData for my app (I don't want to use "many to many" relationship)

[image]

I use `NSFetchedResultsController` to get data. I want to get all tracks of a specific `Playlist` (I use `MagicalRecord` too but don't care it)

```
Playlist *playlist;//a specific playlist
NSFetchRequest *request = [PlayTrack requestAllSortedBy:@"scdCreatedAt" ascending:NO withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"playlist = %@",playlist]];
_resultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                         managedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread]
                                                        sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                          cacheName:NSStringFromClass(self.class)];
//..... perfromFetch...
```

I implemented `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    PlayTrack *playtrack = (PlayTrack *)anObject;
    SCDPlayTrack *track = playtrack.track;//This is what I want
}
```

You see, I only can get `Track` objects by getting `PlayTrack` objects but I want `anObject` is a `Track` object.

What I dream is getting all `Track` of a specific `Playlist` directly!

HOW CAN I DO IT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following fetch request

```
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Track"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
//    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
if (playlist)
{
    NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" ANY playTracks IN %@", playlist.playTracks];
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
}

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scdCreatedAt" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should eliminate the `PlayTrack` entity. It serves no purpose at all because it does not have any additional attributes.

Your data model should be simplified to:

```
PlayList (tracks) <<------->> (playlists) Track
```

You are still thinking in the old relational database way rather than embracing the power of the object graph. This is why you are assuming you need something like a "join table". With mutual to-many relationships, this becomes entirely unnecessary.

Now your "dream" comes true. To get the tracks in a playlist you simply write

```
playlist.tracks
```

Comment: Thanks. But I dont want to use "Many to many" relationship. My dream is about `NSFetchedResultsController` :D

Comment: No problem. You can continue in the relational database world if you so prefer. The fetched results controller has nothing to do with it, nothing at all. -- BTW -also your predicates become much simpler if you use the object graph properly. Good luck for your coding efforts!